# Entering some Stack Overflow pages, I am having a bad user experience (Corporate Network User)

Tags: bug, status-review, login, user-accounts, facebook

Entering some Stack Overflow pages, I am having a bad user experience.

It happens that when entering the main pages where the questions are displayed, it usually takes me a long time to fully load the tab or change the tab status. I have disabled all the plugins and the only thing I cannot do is change the settings of my corporate firewall, but I have noticed that Stack Overflow seems to consume some resources of social networks to the detriment of the user experience.

Then I make the clarification that I log in with my Google account access provider, not Facebook, even social networks are blocked on my local network.

Then in the console section it shows me this message Error:

[image]

***This made me think, something strange is happening here; why does it consume data from Facebook if I don't enter with the Facebook access provider!!!***

Then I proceed to see in network tab of Chrome, **38 seconds to resolve the fail time-out**:

[image]

And so:  the network resource was invalidated

[image]

And so: for some reason I have a websocket open with SO/SE and then I have an overwhelming *delay* immediately...

[image]

I have two questions at this point:

Why does the search for a Facebook image persist when I am not logged into Facebook, even after I have logged in?

Is there a way to disable this option, and have it be saved in a cookie, disable any search option or attempt to connect to Facebook, etc.?

**I repeat: I am not using the Facebook login provider. I have logged in with Google and I have put the avatar manually ...**

---

***Update:***

After placing this post and investigating a little more about my accesses, history, configurations, etc... came to the following conclusion:

This problem may be related to a particular situation that is quite strange but that I already checked.

If the user entered from another device or Internet network to some SO/SE site, and at some point linked his/her Facebook account like access provider; the network of SO/SE sites will continue to try to obtain data from Facebook even if the login has been made with another access provider such as Google.

Users of a corporate network, that do not have access to social networks should follow these steps to eliminate the access record with social networks, can partially solve it:

Step 1: Go to your profile. 
Step 2: Go to the access or login tab. 
Step 3: remove the login record with Facebook it should appear as similar to the example image below the google login.

This will prevent the SO/SE site from trying/continue to connect to the social network account. It even prevented the slow loading of the site or large time with loading status in the tab of Q&A page on SO/SE.

[image]

**How can we reproduce it?:**

- A) Enter with Google and with Facebook from home.
- B) Verify that both are in your setting as access providers.
- C) Get out of your session.
- D) Delete any data, cache of the site.
- E) According to your SO, it looks for a way to block, reset, or timeout the access to any domain or sub-domain of Facebook.
- F) go to Stack Overflow and sign in with your Google account.
- G) Check the questions page of the site.

***I would really hope that the SO/SE developers will find another solution to this situation... I don't see the point of looking for things on Facebook when my access method was with Google...***

---

***Update 2***

I continued to monitor this error on my account and only the socket delay remains pending; which I couldn't solve.

[image]

WebSock Test:

[image]

---

***Update 3***

I have continued to investigate the problem around the websocket and have been able to come to an additional conclusion:

The social network block does not allow SO/ES to load this image/data:

[image]

therefore the websocket understands that the page has not finished loading, therefore by not changing the status of the tab the web socket hangs...

All this occurs due to the persistence of SE/SO consuming data from social networks, even if the logged in user has no relationship with the social networks or access providers.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is one of the rare questions where at first I looked at it and said "ugh here we go again"...... and instead OP laid out a well researched issue, showed how to reproduce it, and explained why it is sketchy as hell. Nice work OP.

Comment: @patricksweeney Sorry for the inconvenience; It seems to me that the answer I had given is not an answer as such, it is a work around, so I have placed it within my question as part of its content and what I have done to search for/monitor this bug. With my limited knowledge and tools, what is not clear to me is why after a certain edition the images used in the post are repeated at the bottom of the post, if someone can solve that I would be grateful.

Comment: that call to `qa.sockets.stackexchange.com`  is meant to establish the websocket connection. It should return a 101 switching protocols and then in the "ws" tab of the developer console you should see heart beats and messages for updates. If your network admin disabled / blocked websocket traffic then that specific cal will never finish.

Comment: @rene how can i check it on console? any reference?

Comment: goto https://websocketstest.com/ and see if that works.

Comment: @rene i have update the post with the result test.

Comment: @rene I really don't understand why the websocket takes so long even if this web socket has nothing to do with the status of the tab, I don't know if you can see how the websocket affects the next item to be downloaded on the network...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWijj.png

Comment: Me neither. It does take up one socket but you have to do a lot of insane other things before you run out of those. And the site should work without a websocket connection, you would only notice some degradation of certain features like live updates etc.

Comment: @rene I already found the reason: apparently it's not the websocket; As I had indicated, the first problem is that the page is consuming this image/url/data: https://graph.facebook.com/1767392173279926/picture?type=large 
apparently the websocket does not work or does not continue its process or execution until the page has been completely loaded; then, while waiting for the image or for this URL to resolve, you have the feeling that the web socket is causing a problem when it is not... it is still the consumption of social network services.

Comment: If you in the Chrome developer console right-click on one of the graph.facebook.com calls you get an option to "Block Request Url". Can you try that and see if that speed things up? That should instruct Chrome to not even attempt the network call for graph.facebook.com, so there should be no blocking/waiting of other requests.

Comment: @rene yes but it is a work around for me only...

Comment: Correct. It is more to confirm we have diagnosed the issue correctly. Thanks for the patience. it is in the hands of the SE dev team now.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 might be something lost in translation, no inconvenience here, you did a great job with this question! Not something I would have ever thought about, but I am glad you noticed it.